# Salesforce CTI softphone screenpop not working

Tags: lightning, cti, twilio, softphone

I have the `Twilo Flex Call Center Adapter Open CTI` installed into Salesforce.

I am System Admin and when I get calls the screen popping works (it opens records or search results).

When other users get calls the screen popping does not work.

Below are my screen pop settings:

[image]

Any ideas what might be causing it to not work for users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed by **right-clicking** on the Chrome Reload button and selecting:

> Empty Cache and Hard Reload

[image]